# Firefox's popping up advertisement windows

Tags: updates, firefox, popup-ads

For more than two weeks my firefox opens popping up advertisement windows. Could there be a gap within Ubuntu update system? I think this way because I only apply updates that are sent by update manager and I use firefox for all my safe and serious works. Meanwhile, I could not get rid off it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Block the popup advertisements from Firefox by installing this Firefox extension: [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/).

Comment: be advised that you are installing an ad-blocker, not just a popup blocker here. It might be a good thing, but it will block more then just popups. This means that you might need to shut it off for some sites to have either all features working, or just to comply with their wishes (some sites do not want you to use an adblocker). Now I'm not saying this is good or bad one way or the other, but you should be aware I guess..

Answer (score 0):

If the popups come randomly* you are having a big problem. Something is fishy. It could be a plugin you installed (maybe not even on purpose) or something else that is opening teh fox.

If they come while browsing, it could just be your settings are different from what you are used to. For instance, you can set the default pop-up blocker like so:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting#w_pop-up-blocker-settings

[image: popup blocker]

<sub>* on sites where you are sure there are no popups (google for instance), or when you are not doing anything</sub>

Comment: I am indeed having popups that are apparently random and not tied to a particular site or user activity.  Very strange.  I have no idea how to track this down.  Is there a way I can log the firefox process to find out how these are opening?

Answer (score 0):

stop phishing scam by using popup blocker.Install some best popup blockers which can block unwanted ads , annoying ads, misleading message and disable tracking.I also suggest you some sites you can up there popup blocker [ad blocker](http://www.ablockpluse.org).